# Is the compiler allowed to turn an lvalue into an rvalue reference if the lvalue is no longer used in its defining scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Consider the following:

```
ComplexObject foo()
{
    ComplexObject temp;
    //Do things with temp
    ComplexObject result(temp, SOME_OTHER_SETTING); //1
    //Do things with result. Do not use temp at all
    return result; //2
}

ComplexObject foo()
{
    ComplexObject temp;
    //Do things with temp
    ComplexObject result(std::move(temp), SOME_OTHER_SETTING); //1
    //Do things with result. Do not use temp at all
    return std::move(result); //2
}
```

with the assumption that ComplexObject has a move constructor which is far more efficient than it's copy constructor.

Is the compiler allowed to effectively transform the first code into the second code, because it knows that ComplexObject cannot be used for the remainder of that block?

Comment: Also, does `ComplexObject` have a non-trivial destructor?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Let's say it contains something like a vector, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not for `temp`, but the compiler can perform other optimizations under the *as-if* rule, which may have the same effect.

For `result`, there is a special rule regarding `return` statements, that will use a move if possible (and elision is preferred over either move or copy).

Comment: The *as-if* rule won't have that effect. If the compiler can't inline the constructors, it can't prove they don't have different observable side-effect and if it can, inlining the copy constructor and eliminating all instructions it can using *as-if* rule is likely to be as efficient and already implemented.

Comment: @JanHudec: That's what I said in my answer.

Comment: That sentence is a bit misleading; the "same effect" lacks context.